# Sharepoint 2013 GetListItems web service returning a list of folders in library, instead of list of files within a folder

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm having a problem being able to get the list of items within a folder, it keeps giving me the list of **folders** in the library, and not the list of files *within* the specified folder.

I'm using a C# program, using the following method to call the web service GetListItems, and it all seems to work up to a point:

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems", RequestNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/", ResponseNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
public System.Xml.XmlNode GetListItems(string listName, string viewName, System.Xml.XmlNode query, System.Xml.XmlNode viewFields, string rowLimit, System.Xml.XmlNode queryOptions, string webID) {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("GetListItems", new object[] {
                listName,
                viewName,
                query,
                viewFields,
                rowLimit,
                queryOptions,
                webID});
    return ((System.Xml.XmlNode)(results[0]));
    }
```

The values of the parameters are as follows:

```
listName = "Letters"
viewName = null
query = null
viewFields.OuterXml = "<ViewFields>
                            <FieldRef Name=\"ID\" /> 
                            <FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />
                            <FieldRef Name=\"Modified\" />
                            <FieldRef Name=\"Status\" />
                            <FieldRef Name=\"_UIVersion\" />
                            <FieldRef Name=\"_UIVersionString\" />
                            <FieldRef Name=\"EpisodeId\" />
                        </ViewFields>"
rowLimit = null
queryOptions.OuterXml = "<QueryOptions>
                            <IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
                            <Folder>http://D3TVCAPP-APP02.test.local/Letters/ABBOTT, Nash  _489611</Folder>
                            <DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>
                         </QueryOptions>"
webID = null
```

And it actually returns a result, it is hitting the service ok, the result looks like this:

```
results.OuterXml =  
    "<listitems xmlns:s=\"uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882\" xmlns:dt=\"uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882\" xmlns:rs=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset\" xmlns:z=\"#RowsetSchema\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\">
        <rs:data ItemCount=\"2\">
            <z:row 
                ows_ID=\"84\" 
                ows_Modified=\"2021-06-09T09:50:11Z\" 
                ows__UIVersion=\"1\" 
                ows__UIVersionString=\"0.1\" 
                ows__ModerationStatus=\"2\" 
                ows__Level=\"2\" 
                ows_UniqueId=\"84;#{C8E8EC38-6DD5-4275-873A-B829BA850A54}\" 
                ows_owshiddenversion=\"1\" 
                ows_FSObjType=\"84;#1\" 
                ows_Created_x0020_Date=\"84;#2021-06-09T09:50:11Z\" 
                ows_ProgId=\"84;#\" 
                ows_FileLeafRef=\"84;#ABBOTT, Nash  _489611\" 
                ows_PermMask=\"0x7fffffffffffffff\" 
                ows_FileRef=\"84;#Letters/ABBOTT, Nash  _489611\" 
                ows_Editor=\"1;#John Smith\" 
                ows_MetaInfo=\"84;#\" 
                ows_Last_x0020_Modified=\"84;#2021-06-09T09:50:14Z\" 
            />
            <z:row 
                ows_ID=\"3\" 
                ows_Modified=\"2020-11-04T13:02:42Z\" 
                ows__UIVersion=\"1\" 
                ows__UIVersionString=\"0.1\" 
                ows__ModerationStatus=\"2\" 
                ows__Level=\"2\" 
                ows_UniqueId=\"3;#{1CA7B690-BF90-41EC-A5EA-E910C8D72376}\" 
                ows_owshiddenversion=\"1\" 
                ows_FSObjType=\"3;#1\" 
                ows_Created_x0020_Date=\"3;#2020-11-04T13:02:42Z\" 
                ows_ProgId=\"3;#\" 
                ows_FileLeafRef=\"3;#SMITH, JOHN  _483835\" 
                ows_PermMask=\"0x7fffffffffffffff\" 
                ows_FileRef=\"3;#Letters/SMITH, JOHN  _483835\" 
                ows_Editor=\"1;#John Smith\" 
                ows_MetaInfo=\"3;#\" 
                ows_Last_x0020_Modified=\"3;#2020-11-06T16:59:03Z\" 
            />
        </rs:data>
    </listitems>"
```

Apologies for the wall of code, I just hope that someone can help me and want to provide as much info as possible.  I can't figure this one out, I feel like I'm doing everything right.  Anyone got any idea what I 'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

C# Programming give for developers two options to consumes SharePoint data; seeing  your code, I think you try to consume SharePoint data using ***REST API approach***. The ***REST API approach*** is commonly used to make interfaces with SharePoint and external Systems written by other programming languages (different of C#) and not used a lot by C# developer community in frequency; but, it's need to be clear: it's not a rule and it's not impossible to consumes SharePoint data using REST API from C#, but this is more "difficultly" comparing with ***CSOM approach***.

Now, I will show you an example using ***CSOM approach*** to get files from specific folder, and you get your conclusions:

1. First of all, download and install [SharePoint 2013 Client SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585);
2. After installed SDK, create some standalone app, like a Console App using .NET Framework 4.5 or later;
3. Add in References (search in Framework) two DLLs: `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll`;
4. Add this code-file bellow in your Console App Project:

> 

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Security;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace SharePoint.Csom.Approach
{
    public class SharePointDocumentModel
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public string Url { get; set; }

        public string Version { get; set; }
    }

    public class SharePointDocuments : IDisposable
    {
        private bool _disposed = false;

        protected readonly ClientContext _clientContext;

        public SharePointDocuments(string sharepointSiteUrl, string user, SecureString password)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sharepointSiteUrl) || !sharepointSiteUrl.StartsWith("http"))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Impossible to connect with invalid URL.");
            }
            this._clientContext = new ClientContext(sharepointSiteUrl);
            this._clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
            this._clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);
        }

        public IEnumerable<SharePointDocumentModel> GetFiles(string folderRelativeURL)
        {
            Web web = this._clientContext.Web;
            this._clientContext.Load(web);
            this._clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Folder folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl + folderRelativeURL);
            this._clientContext.Load(folder);
            this._clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            FileCollection fileCol = folder.Files;
            this._clientContext.Load(fileCol);
            this._clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (File file in fileCol)
            {
                string fileVersion = null;
                FileVersionCollection oFileVersionCollection = file.Versions;
                this._clientContext.Load(oFileVersionCollection);
                this._clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (FileVersion oFileVersion in oFileVersionCollection)
                {
                    fileVersion = oFileVersion.VersionLabel;
                }
                yield return new SharePointDocumentModel()
                {
                    FileName = file.Name,
                    Url = file.ServerRelativeUrl,
                    Version = fileVersion
                };
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
        }

        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (this._disposed)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (null != this._clientContext)
                {
                    this._clientContext.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this._disposed = true;
        }

        ~SharePointDocuments()
        {
            this.Dispose(false);
        }
    }
}
```

> 

5. At Program class and in Main method, add this code:

> 

```
List<SharePoint.Csom.Approach.SharePointDocumentModel> files = new List<SharePoint.Csom.Approach.SharePointDocumentModel();
using (SharePoint.Csom.Approach.SharePointDocuments sharepoint = new SharePoint.Csom.Approach.SharePointDocuments("http://D3TVCAPP-APP02.test.local", "user", "password"))
{
    files = sharepoint.GetFiles("/Letters/ABBOTT, Nash  _489611").ToList();
}
```

> 

6. Voilá!

After made your tests, give us the feedback.

Thanks.